# Pre-Selected Multiselect from MySql DB Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

**I have 2 Mysql tables (tbl_subjects AND tbl_courses).**

```
tbl_subjects
id | subject_name |
1  | english      |
2  | maths        |
3  | Physics      |

tbl_courses
id | my_subjects |
1  | 1,3         |
```

**html & php code for Multiselect list**

```
$sql_subjects = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects WHERE id IN ( 1,3 )"));

<select name="subjects[]" multiple="multiple" size="7">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql ))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$subject_name = $row['subject_name '];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php if($sql_subjects['id'] == $id) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>> <?php echo $subject_name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

As you see in the above code, there should be **2 pre selected** values, but i only got result of 1st one.You can see in image also [image]

Comment: This does not look like a standard select box, how are you creating it?

Comment: This is jquery UI Multiselect, you can check it online here http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: Try it without the multiselect plugin first. Also check the PHP-generated markup.

Comment: I checked with simple multi select also, but i think the main problem is while loop which dosn't work inside another while loop @wroniasty

Comment: problem here is with ur $sql_subjects['id'] . this will have only one id. i.e '1'... since it is taking the first id form the table.

Comment: @bipen ya i think the problem is that one, but i try while loop on that query also and the result is nothing then

Comment: ok try while loop there... push it into array say temparray... and then in if condition check in_array($id,temparray).i think this should work..

Comment: Well, you are comparing the wrong variable. You need to compare against the comma-separated ID values from `tbl_courses`, right now you just compare with the ID from `tbl_subjects`. Better do not ask "How?" but "Why?". Only if you understand your problem, you can solve it. It looks like you need an additional database query for that, as the variable you want to look into does not yet exists. Consider to use a different database library that better supports your needs like `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @bipen can you please elaborate, i dont understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql_subjects=array();    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects WHERE id IN ( 1,3 )"))){
    $sql_subjects[] = $row['id'];
}
```

and in your html part

```
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php if(in_array($id,$sql_subjects) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>> <?php echo $subject_name; ?></option>
```

Comment: :).. have fun coding.... and yes.. if u know (1,3) is ur ids to check.
like in  this query (SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects WHERE id IN ( 1,3 ))..then u can directly do $sql_subjects=array(1,3); instead of running a query and creating an array....

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `mysql_fetch_array()` will generate the first row only. We need to use the loop to retrieve all the rows.

Instead you know the id then why you retrieving again from database use in_array() to check,

```
<select name="subjects[]" multiple="multiple" size="7">
<?php
    $ids = array(1,2);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php if(in_array($id,$ids)) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>> <?php echo $subject_name; ?></option>
    <?php
    } 
?>
</select>
```